# sfc /scannow failed to repair some files

Tags: windows-7

> Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"setup_wm.exe" of
>   Microsoft-Windows-MediaPlayer-Setup, Version = 6.1.7601.17514,
>   
> Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"Libeay32.dll" of
>   smarttech.openssl.0.9.8, Version = 1.0.1.0,

I have used the orignial win7 disk to perform repair to run again the `sfc /scannow`, but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: SFC can only repair files that are normally part of the Windows Compondant Store ( i.e.WinSxS ).  OpenSSL library file does not fit that bill.  You must also have a regional version of Windows 7, one that does not normally come with Windows Media Player, can you confirm that?

Comment: Install this update: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2966583 and run **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth** to repair the setup_wm.exe. the openssl is not part of Windows, so it can't be repaired.

Comment: @magicandre1981 dism cleanup commands do not work for Windows 7 do they? I thought this was introduced in W8.

Comment: Hmm `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image` seems to be supported on Win 7 but not `/Scanhealth`

Comment: install the update that I posted. It brings scanhelath to Win7 which does the same like RestoreHealth in 8+.

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed the update and use DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth. Unfortunately, the problem remains.